# How to render live session of website and also interact with it

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, logrocket

So there are a few tools to record and view live sessions of users on your website using js sdks's like:

1. logrocket,
2. hotjar,
3. https://github.com/rrweb-io/rrweb
4. https://github.com/openreplay/openreplay
5. etc ...

Is there any open source tools or any method of viewing a user's live session with the site but also being able to interact with the user's live session?

If user "John" was learning how to use the site and wanted help and an example on how to do something, he could contact a site admin and the site admin could see John's live session like logrocket does, and with John's permission he could take control and interact with john's session and show how to use the site.

The way I thought something like this would work is serializing the dom and showing the dom to the site admin and when clicking on an element it would send that click event through a websocket to the user's (john's) browser and it would execute the event from the site admin on the user's session.

Comment: Its totally possible to build this sort of web-app - the question is rather whether anybody wants that (and pays for it). In reality, the site-admin would not need any 'permission' to 'hijack' a users session. You probably see how questionable this sort of setup is in terms of privacy. That's also why the tools you mentioned are generally not compatible with GDPR as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of an old question, but one of the projects you mention there "OpenReplay" provides live session replay, the ability to interact with them (through a live video call directly from within the web app and giving you the ability to also input and control a secondary mouse to show them where to click) and at the same time, the tracker will sanitize any sensitive information to make sure you, as an outsider, can't see any private data.

Check out their product called "[Assist](https://openreplay.com/feature-assist.html)", which is a plug-in to the standard tracker, you can use it for free as part of their free-tier on the SaaS or self-hosted options.